# Is there a way to reference data contained in fields on related record using formula field?

Tags: formula, customization, netsuite, record

I want to display the taxcode custom field on invoice records

According to Netsuite Help, the format for the formula would be like that:
{taxcode.customfieldid}, knowing that (taxcode is the field id for the taxcode field on the lines of invoice record. customfieldid is the field id for the custom field on the TaxCode record)

PS: customfieldid is a free-text

I have tried possibilities like:
{invoice.item.taxcode.customfieldid}
{item.taxcode.customfieldid}

But I still get this error "ERROR: Field 'taxcode.customfieldid' Not Found"

how can I fix this? Can anyone provide some guidance on this issue?

Comment: Are you working on `Search` ?. Can you please provide your code snippet?

Comment: hello Vikes, I want to use this custom field in "Advanced PDF/HTML Template", and I added this custom field on "Transaction line fields".

Answer (score 0):

Generally Netsuite will only look one level away from the record you are on.

In your case you should create a new transaction line field (say custcol_tax_extra) and source that from the taxcode so when a tax code is selected that value is pulled up onto the line.

Then your xml:

```
<#list record.item as item>${item.custcol_tax_extra}...
```